# Are you allowed to use と in front of が?

Tags: grammar

For example, if I were saying "This was made by him and I," would it be possible to write it as "これは彼と私が作りました。"?

Are you allowed to list multiple things as the subject of the sentence?

Comment: Totally irrelevant but (1) unlike English, "I and [someone]" is the most natural order in Japanese unless under special context; (2) If you want to put "this" in subject's place, 彼と私**で**作りました sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, and your example sentence looks perfectly fine. You don't have to change the verb form because there is not plural declension in Japanese.